# Ubuntu 23.04 Headphone Microphone is not recognized

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I have a MONSTER TULPAR T7 V20.5 laptop(a foreign brand). I have Ubuntu 23.04 installed with the kernel version of 6.2.0-20-generic x86_64.

The problem I am having is that my headphone microphone is not recognized. I searched almost everywhere on the internet and tried bunch of codecs from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html)

I tried the suggested solutions with pulseaudio, hdajackretask, echomixer etc. Nothing worked so far. I was unable to make my laptop recognize the headphone mic.

As far as I know, my laptop brand was made by Clevo and that seems to be the problem.

The output of cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec is:

```
Codec: Realtek ALC256
Codec: Intel Alderlake-P HDMI
Codec: Nvidia GPU 9f HDMI/DP
```

The system info:

Hardware Model: MONSTER TULPAR T7 V20.5

Firmware version: N.1.02MON04

Memory: 16.0 GB

Processor: 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-12700H × 20

Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3060 Laptop GPU / Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)

OS Name: Ubuntu 23.04

OS Type: 64-bit

GNOME Version: 44.0

Windowing System: X11

Kernel Version: Linux 6.2.0-20-generic

Nvidia driver: 525.105.17